# Sum of 2nd and 3rd column for same value in 1st column

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, scripting

I want to sum the value in column 2nd and 3rd column for same value in 1st column

```
1555971000 6 1   
1555971000 0 2  
1555971300 2 0  
1555971300 3 0
```

Output would be like

```
1555971000 6 3  
1555971300 5 0
```

I have tried below command

```
awk -F" " '{b[$2]+=$1} END { for (i in b) { print b[i],i } } '
```

but this seems to be for only one column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way with reading Input_file 2 times and it will provide output in same sequence as Input_file's sequence.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]+=$3;next} ($1 in a){print $1,a[$1],b[$1];delete a[$1]}' Input_file Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

if data in 'd' without sort, tried on gnu awk,

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=1} {if($1==a||f){b+=$2;c+=$3;f=0} else{print a,b,c;b=$2;c=$3} a=$1} END{print a,b,c}' d
```

with sort gnu awk

```
awk '{w[NR]=$0} END{asort(w);f=1;for(;i++<NR;){split(w[i],v);if(v[1]==a||f){f=0;b+=v[2];c+=v[3]} else{print a,b,c;b=v[2];c=v[3];} a=v[1]} print a,b,c;}' d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk` by first saving the fields in the first record, and then for all subsequent records, comparing if the first field matches, if so, add the contents of fields two and three and continue. If the first field fails to match, then output your first field and the running-sums, e.g.

```
awk '{ 
    if ($1 == a) { 
        b+=$2; c+=$3; 
    }
    else {
        print a, b, c; a=$1; b=$2; c=$3;
    }
} END { print a, b, c; }' file
```

With your input in `file`, you can copy and paste the foregoing into your terminal and obtain, the following:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '{
>     if ($1 == a) {
>         b+=$2; c+=$3;
>     }
>     else {
>         print a, b, c; a=$1; b=$2; c=$3;
>     }
> } END { print a, b, c; }' file

1555971000 6 3
1555971300 5 0
```

**Using `awk` Arrays**

A shorter more succinct alternative using arrays that does not require your input to be in sorted order would be:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2; b[$1]+=$3} END{ for (i in a) print i, a[i], b[i] }' file
```

(same output)

Using arrays allows the summing of columns for like field1 to work equally well if your data file contained the following lines in random order, e.g.

```
1555971300 2 0
1555971000 0 2
1555971000 6 1
1555971300 3 0
```

Comment: Actually, the BEGIN should just be removed `:)` I started out in one direction and finished in another.

Comment: @DavidCRankin your first solution does not work if you don't have all the column 1 `$1` in sequentially. For example, move the input line 1 to line 4 (at the end of the file)

Comment: Yes, that is explained in the presentation of the 2nd approach. The first was done without arrays, the second introduces them. Good eye.

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` that would work regardless of any order of records whether or not they are not sorted :

```
awk '{r[$1]++}
     r[$1]==1{o[++c]=$1}
     {f[$1]+=$2;s[$1]+=$3}
     END{for(i=1;i<=c;i++){print o[i],f[o[i]],s[o[i]]}}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when you wrote:

```
awk -F" " '{b[$2]+=$1} END { for (i in b) { print b[i],i } } '
```

you meant to write:

```
awk '{ b[$1]+=$2 } END{ for (i in b) print i,b[i] }'
```

It shouldn't be a huge leap to figure out:

```
$ awk '{ b[$1]+=$2; c[$1]+=$3 } END{ for (i in b) print i,b[i],c[i] }' file
1555971000 6 3
1555971300 5 0
```

Please get the book "Effective Awk Programming", 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and just read a paragraph or 2 about fields and arrays.